# Get actorRef in akka-stream 1.0 when using Source.actorPublisher and a FlowGraph

Tags: akka-stream

My question is somewhere related to : [Accessing the underlying ActorRef of an akka stream Source created by Source.actorRef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30785011/5299707)
with some differences :

1. I'm using akka-stream experimental 1.0
2. I'm using the actorPublisher model
3. I'm using a FlowGraph dsl for stream definition with parallel processing

I don't find a way to get an actorRef to send a message to the Actor Publisher instance held by the Source.

> ```
>  def run(implicit system: ActorSystem) = {
>    import system.dispatcher
>    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
>
>    val source = Source.actorPublisher[TestRequest](TestActor.props).map { request => request.event }
>
>    //Implementation in subpackage
>    val sinkLevel1 = Sinks.sinkLevel1 
>    val sinkLevel2 = Sinks.sinkLevel2
>
>    //Implementation in subpackage
>    val stageTriage = FlowStages.stageTriage    
>    val stageEvalProcess1 = FlowStages.stageEvalProcess1
>    val stageEvalProcess2 = FlowStages.stageEvalProcess2
>
>    val pipeline = FlowGraph.closed(){ implicit builder => 
>      import FlowGraph.Implicits._
>
>      val stageDispatchByRuleLevels = builder.add(Broadcast[TriagedSystemEvent](2))
>
>      source ~> stageTriage ~> stageDispatchByRuleLevels
>                               stageDispatchByRuleLevels ~> stageEvalProcess1 ~> sinkLevel1
>                               stageDispatchByRuleLevels ~> stageEvalProcess2 ~> sinkLevel2
>
>    }
>
>    pipeline.run()
>
>  }
> ```

Thanks for help !

Oliver

Answer (score 1):

Based on Noah's answer in the linked question, if you add

```
val ref = pipeline.run()
```

you can then send messages to ref, like

```
ref ! ...
```