# How can I get the ActorRef from Source.actorRef()?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I want to do some server-side events (SSE) to a web app.  I think I have all the SSE plumbing up and going.  I now need to create a Source on the Akka HTTP side of the house.

I found you can do something like this:

```
val source = Source.actorRef(5, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
```

What I want to do is somehow "publish" to this source, presumably by sending an actor a message.  I see from the docs that this call creates `Source<T,ActorRef>`.

How can I get this ActorRef instance so I can send messages to it?

Comment: Did you use https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/sse.html or are you writing this infrastructure yourself?

Comment: Writing myself for this example.  Thanks for the link tho!  If my exercise goes well the grown-up version may well need something like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the underlying ActorRef of an akka stream Source created by Source.actorRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785011/accessing-the-underlying-actorref-of-an-akka-stream-source-created-by-source-act)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the materialized `ActorRef` from `Source.actorRef`, the stream has to be running. For example, let's say that you want to send the SSE payload data (in the form of a `String`) to this actor, which converts that data to [`ServerSentEvent`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/sse/ServerSentEvent.html) objects to send to the client. You could do something like:

```scala
val (actor, sseSource) =
  Source.actorRef[String](5, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
        .map(s => /* convert String to ServerSideEvent */)
        .keepAlive(1.second, () => ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
        .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[ServerSentEvent])(Keep.both)
        .run()

// (ActorRef, Source[ServerSentEvent, NotUsed])
```

Now you can send messages to the materialized actor:

```scala
actor ! "quesadilla"
```

And use `sseSource` in your route:

```scala
path("events") {
  get {
    complete(sseSource)
  }
}
```

Note that there is no backpressure with this approach (i.e., messages to the actor are fired-and-forgotten).